# Semi-transparent border on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, transparent

I'm trying to make a button that looks like this:

[image: Button]

The button has

- transparent background color
- non-transparent title
- semi-transparent white border color

What's the best way to do this? I know how to achieve the first two items, but how do I get the semi-transparent white border color?

Comment: you can set up a semi-transparent border for the button any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the button's layer's properties:

```
yourButton.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
yourButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:178/255.0 green:170/255.0 blue:156/255.0 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
```

(Change the values so it looks good, alpha makes it semi-transparent)

Also, you'll need this if you don't have the circle yet:

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.size.width/2;
```

EDIT: As @holex suggested, a better way to calculate the cornerRadius is:

```
CGFloat radius = MIN(yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height) / 2.0
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
```

Comment: `yourButton.frame.size.width/2` only applies if your button is squared.

Comment: I would go for calculating the corner radius: `CGFloat _radius = MIN(yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height) / 2.0;`